# Class backend/UsersController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to separate Backend and Frontend in my project. I have Created two direcotry inside Controllers, named: frondend and backend. I have UsersController inside backend directory. 
I have added route for UsersController

`Route::group(array('prefix' => 'backend'), function() {
    Route::get('users', array('as' => 'users', 'uses' => 'backend/UsersController@index'));
});`

I have used namespace as

`namespace Controllers/backend;`

in my UsersController.
I run the command `php artisan dump-autoload`. When I try to access the routes as `codefacet.loc/backend/users`, it says

`ReflectionException

Class backend/UsersController does not exist`

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'backend'), function() {
    Route::get('users', array('as' => 'user_index', 'uses' => 'UsersController@index'));
});

the other way you can achieve that is 

Route::group(['namespace'=>'your-namespace-in-full'], function()
{
    Route::controller('users/index', 'UsersController',array(
        'index'=>'users.index',
    ));
});
```

Comment: Sorry, Its not solving the problem. @osleonard. Need to try something else

Comment: `<?php namespace Controllers/backend; class UsersController extends \BaseController { /** * Display a listing of the resource. * * @return Response */ public function index() { return View::make('backend.users.index'); }`

Comment: sorry i dont know how to actually paste as show in editor with line breaking

Comment: your namespacing is wrong thats why, i assume you are either autoloading with psr-4 or psr-0 so refer to what I just pasted PSR-0 vendor/<VendorName>/<ProjectName>/src/<NamespaceVendor>/<NamespaceProject>/File.‌​php PSR-4  vendor/<VendorName>/<ProjectName>/src/File.php for better understanding consult this post